# send video files to server from multiple clients

Tags: c#, video-streaming, client-server

I'm using this client/server code which i found on the net for communication:

client:

```
    public void Send(string name, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("address");
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress[0], 5656);
            Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

            string fileName = "somefile";
            string filePath = path;
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);

            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, fileName)); 
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);

            clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);
            clientSock.Send(clientData);
            MessageBox.Show("file has been send: " + fileName);

            clientSock.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Sending fail." + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

server:

```
public void Receive()
    {
        try
        {
            lblInfo.Content = "That program can transfer small file. I've test up to 850kb file";
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            sock.Bind(ipEnd);
            sock.Listen(100);
            Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();
            // 1024 * 25.000 = 25mb max that can be received at once with this program.
            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 25000];
            string receivedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\";

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);

            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

            lblInfo.Content = "Client: connected & File started received.";

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);

            lblInfo.Content = "File: received & saved at path: " + receivedPath;

            bWrite.Close();
            clientSock.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblInfo.Content = "File Receiving fail." + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

this code works fine for 1 client that transferes a file to the server. i was wondering how i can change this code to make it communicate with multiple clients that can send files to the server?

also, the server code 'hangs' at `Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();` and waits untill it receives something. It would be nice if there is a 'listener' that listens for new incomming files and then loop through the code, instead of endless waiting at that line.

Im new to client/server programming and all ears to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have explanations for creating your loops for new connections :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz10xcwh.aspx

```
IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
listener.Bind(ipEnd);
listener.Listen(100);

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
Socket handler = listener.Accept();

while (true)
{
    // 1024 * 25.000 = 25mb max that can be received at once with this program.
    byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 25000];
    string receivedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\";

    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(clientData);
    int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
    string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

    BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
    bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, bytesRec - 4 - fileNameLen);
    bWrite.Close();
}

//dont forget to close handler at server shutdown
//handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
//handler.Close();
```

Comment: hi, i've read that link you gave me. i'm really new to client/server programming. where do i set those line of code in my code? thanks in advance

Comment: then if you want to accept several connections simultaneaously you will have to handle the client messages in threads.

Comment: yes thats what i need too for this project. handeling several connections simultaneously. how would those threads look like?

Comment: Create a new class which will contain a method whith your while loop, you'll just have to pass the socket handler before starting your thread. Then they will process the data sent by the client. If you want example of thread creation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: but that while loop only gets walked through it once. and if it loops through it again, i get this error: Index and count must refer to a location within the buffer. Parameter name: bytes. and i just made that thread, same error.

Comment: It depends on what the client is sending. You have to make sure '4+fileNameLen' and 'bytesRec - 4 - fileNameLen' are coherent with your buffer length. Do you send filename each type you send data or only when you initiate connection. This is building your proctocol and has nothing to do with the connection mecanism...

Comment: im sending a video file which is about 21 megs. the buffer is big enough to get all the data. but there are multiple clients sending video files to the server. this can be simultaneous or not. right now it tries to walk the while loop twice. the second time it walks, i get that error or an error about a path it cant be found. the first iteration, everything goes fine.

Comment: if i remove the while loop, or just comment it out, it works like a charm. but this wouldn't work for multiple connections simultaneously.

Comment: you shouldn't send 20Mo in one packet, you will have poor performances, in real conditions. Should split your files in smaller buffers

Comment: how do i split the file in the client code? and how do i know if i received everything on the server side? im new to client/server programming. can you show me how this is done? i wouldn't be asking here if there were some good examples on the net.